# File Handling in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is there anyway to do Files Handling in Objective-C? I am just trying to do simple read and write and can use 'c' but i am force to use Objective-C classes for that :@. I am looking into NSInputStream, but its going over my head. Is there any tutorial which explains how to use NSInputStream?

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C. You can just do file I/O in C, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is *really* simple I/O, you can just tell an object to initialize itself from, or write itself to, a filesystem path or URL. This works with several Foundation classes, including NSString, NSData, NSArray, and NSDictionary among others.

Try starting out by looking at the following two NSString methods:

[- initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:)

[- writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:)

Comment: You're welcome. I love the Foundation framework for this and a bazillion other reasons.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with basic file i/o when I first hit it in Obj-C as well.  I ended up using NSFileHandle to get C style access to my file.  Here's a basic example:

```
// note: myFilename is an NSString containing the full path to the file

// create the file
NSFileManager *fManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
if ([fManager createFileAtPath:myFilename contents:nil attributes:nil] != YES) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create file: %@", myFilename);
}
[fManager release]; fManager = nil;

// open the file for updating
NSFileHandle *myFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:myFilename];
if (myFile == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open file for updating: %@", myFilename);
}

// truncate the file so it is guaranteed to be empty
[myFile truncateFileAtOffset:0];

// note: rawData is an NSData object

// write data to a file
[myFile writeData:rawData];

// close the file handle
[myFile closeFile]; myFile = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find apple's guides short and to the point.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html

Comment: I am also reading this from last 30 min, but its not helping me :(